# Move a data to another column in the same table (MS SQL)

Tags: sql-server

How do I move a sentence to another column?

I want to move ET** from fælge to the ET column.
Currently I am getting result like this:

```
   Fælge                                 ET
   6 x 15 ET45      
   7 x 16 ET38
   6x14 ET35|8.5x20 ET36|10x20 ET30
```

But I want result like below:

```
  Fælge                               ET  
  6x15                                45
  7x16                                38
  6x14|8.5x20|10x20                   35|36|30
```

I had been using this query to replace a characters with another but i am not sure how to move a sentence to another column with wildcard characters

I had been using this script down below to change out some of the letters in the fælge column:

```
 use [OminiData]
    UPDATE [dbo].[test]
    SET  [Fælge] = REPLACE([Fælge],'*','x')
    WHERE [Fælge] LIKE '%*%'
```

Here is my table: 
[image]´

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything and found it to not work?

Comment: What is your actual table? and what query are you re trying? Can you provid more info?

Comment: my actual table is [dbo].[test]

Comment: i am not sure what you mean with the table i trying to manipulate 
but i had been using that query i had posted to change some letter in the fælge column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out a way to do it just by using

```
UPDATE [dbo].[test]
SET  [Fælge] = REPLACE([Fælge],'6x15','')
```

and then export and import it to the right columns but it took a while to get the data as i wanted but it was still faster than if i should manualy edit 64k records

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via string manipulation.

```
declare @faelge varchar(25)

set @faelge = '7 x 16 ET38'

select replace(left(@faelge, patindex('%ET%', @faelge) - 1), ' ', '') as 'Faelge', 
right(@faelge, len(@faelge) - patindex('%ET%', @faelge) - 1) as 'ET'
```

I am using a single variable as an example where you would use the column from your table.

Comment: from that one you can just type in difrent stuff at 
`set @faelge = '7 x 16 ET38'`  like `set @faelge = try ETthis'`

and then it will show  `try` under fælge and  `this` under ET which are not some of the data inside my table and it doesn't add that to my table

Answer (score 0):

Please try below.
 
It will breakdown two columns after and before the word 'ET'

```
    SELECT LEFT(Fælge,LEN(Fælge)-CHARINDEX('ET',Fælge)) AS Fælge
,RIGHT(Fælge,LEN(Fælge)-CHARINDEX('ET',Fælge)) AS ET from [dbo].[Test]
```

Comment: that moving everything after E over to ET colum so the result looks like 
`6x15 E` `T45|7x16ET40` i had updatet it with a picture where you can see it

Comment: Just changed the quey. From your info I assumed that the first colum had fixed length for (6X15)